# How do i retrieve information from an XML file on a daily basis automatically? Timers necessary?

Tags: xml, timer

If there is an XML file generated everyday and I need to retrieve certain vital information from it on an everyday basis how can I write a program to make this happen automatically at a specified time. People say use timer events. Which tool should I use? How should I go about this? Please help!

Comment: Does this program run constantly, like a service, or does it just need to run once a day?

Comment: Do you have an OS to run on, a programming language of choice?

Comment: Please specify what kind of language/environment: would a unix shell script be suitable?

Answer (score 0):

A suggested approach would be using a script in Python (just because I prefer it, but can be any other), on a Linux environment and using crontab, to retrieve the info at a specific time.

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crontab
```

You were not clear if the XML file is local, or remote, and need to handle that with your software.

An example of Python parsing a XML is here:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python
```

If the XML is on a HTTP server, I would recoment Python Requests module.